# Implementing tag clouds with CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, tag-cloud

I did a little research on tag clouds, and I ended up choosing a schema similar to the Wordpress one seen in this page: http://www.pui.ch/phred/archives/2005/04/tags-database-schemas.html

Currently, the tables that I have created is: `Posts`, `PostsTagMaps`, `PostsTags`

1) Would I need to create a table for `PostsTagMaps` even if I don't plan on using a controller?

2) A `Post` hasMany `PostTagMaps`. I'm not sure where should I be defining this relationship. I think it should be the `Post` model, but then I would have to join the `PostsTags` table to `PostTagsMaps` then join it to `Posts`, so I wanted to ask for some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to follow Cake conventions (which will look very similar to the solution you linked to). You'll have three tables:

`posts`, `tags`, `posts_tags`

Then your `Post` model HABTM `Tag` model. The join table will automatically be used by Cake to save and retrieve the information. Check [the book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasandbelongstomany-habtm) for more information on setting up your schema.

Cake is flexible enough where you can do it however you want, but if it's a basic sort of posts-tags relationship, the convention method is the way to go.

If you want to use a custom model/table like `PostsTagMaps`, then do this by using the 'with' key in your HABTM relationship definition. The 'with' key tells Cake to use a specific model (and therefore a specific table) instead of an automatically generated version. In this case, your tag model sounds like it's `PostsTags` and your HABTM table is `PostsTagMaps`, so the 'with' key on `Post` HABTM `PostsTag` would be `PostsTagMap`.